# Mocha with Blanket, Babel and LCOV reporter

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, blanket.js

Hiho,

I've got a problem with my Mocha configuration. I've got ES6 code which should be compiled by Babel and then I want to get coverage (in LCOV format) of this ES6 code.

My approach to this problem was to use `mocha`, `mocha-lcov-reporter`, `babel` and `blanket` packages. Code structure is:

```
-- src
----- ...
-- test
----- spec
-------- something.spec.js
-------- ...
----- blanket.js
```

Where specs are in `test/spec` directory (matches also `*.spec.js` pattern) and `blanket.js` is:

```
require('blanket')({
    pattern: require('path').join(__dirname, '..', 'src')
});
```

Command which I prepared is:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha $(find test -name '*.spec.js') --recursive --compilers js:babel/register -r test/blanket -R mocha-lcov-reporter
```

So, it should run Mocha tests for all `*.spec.js` files, compiling them by Babel and starting `test/blanket.js` file before.

After starting this command I get `Error: Line 1: Unexpected reserved word` error from `esprima.js`. When I run it without requiring test/blanket file it run without problems, but ofc I haven't coverage.

Has anyone tried to do so? Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Okey, problem already resolved, but without Babel (native ES6 instead); I've done it another way. I've used `istanbul-harmony` and `mocha` packages. Then the command is:

```
./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- $(find test -name '*.spec.js') -R spec -u exports
```

Comment: You shouldn't even need `istanbul-harmony` at this point.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621079/running-mocha-istanbul-babel) for more info.