# Running Mocha + Istanbul + Babel

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, istanbul

I'm having some issues while running Istanbul with Mocha and the Babel compiler.

All my tests are running just fine, but after all the tests done it shows me this message:

```
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
```

And it is not producing any coverage report.

The command that I am running is:

```sh
NODE_ENV=test istanbul cover _mocha -- --require babel-core/register --recursive
```

The project is hosted on GitHub:
https://github.com/weslleyaraujo/react-flux-puzzle/tree/feat/unit-tests-24

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: i had this issue recently - you have to follow the flow used by grunt-istanbul I believe which is ... 'instrument', 'mochacli', 'storeCoverage', 'makeReport' (although grunt istanbul is doing it for you in this scenario whereas you are doing it from command line) - so i think you need to 'instrument' your files first - not exactly sure what that means but when i instrument it re-create the files in another dir, and then i think you run mocha against those files - not 100% sure - but definitely instrument first

Comment: @weslley-araujo If you are satisfied by my answer, can you accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: **istanbul 1.0.0-alpha.2** now allows Babel generated code, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35976233/1480391

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using Babel 6.x, let's say we have file `test/pad.spec.js`:

```
import pad from '../src/assets/js/helpers/pad';
import assert from 'assert';

describe('pad', () => {
  it('should pad a string', () => {
    assert.equal(pad('foo', 4), '0foo');
  });
});
```

Install a bunch of crap:

```
$ npm install babel-istanbul babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 mocha
```

Create a `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Run the tests:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover \   
node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- test/pad.spec.js


  pad
    ✓ should pad a string


  1 passing (8ms)

=============================================================================
Writing coverage object [/Volumes/alien/projects/forked/react-flux-puzzle/coverage/coverage.json]
Writing coverage reports at [/Volumes/alien/projects/forked/react-flux-puzzle/coverage]
=============================================================================

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 4/4 )
Branches     : 66.67% ( 4/6 ), 1 ignored
Functions    : 100% ( 1/1 )
Lines        : 100% ( 3/3 )
================================================================================
```

**UPDATE**:  I've had success using `nyc` (which consumes `istanbul`) instead of `istanbul`/`babel-istanbul`.  This is somewhat less complicated.  To try it:

Install stuff (you can remove `babel-istanbul` and `babel-cli`):

```
$ npm install babel-core babel-preset-es2015 mocha nyc
```

Create `.babelrc` as above.

Execute this:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/nyc --require babel-core/register node_modules/.bin/mocha \ 
test/pad.spec.js
```

...which should give you similar results.  By default, it puts coverage info into `.nyc-output/`, and prints a nice text summary in the console.

*Note:* You can remove `node_modules/.bin/` from any of these commands when placing the command in `package.json`'s `scripts` field.

Comment: Thanks @boneskull :)

It seems that everything is working fine now!

after babel update I was getting confused about those new configs..

Comment: @boneskull Do you have to use babel-node? Is `$ babel-istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec --compilers js:babel-core/register` not sufficient. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @cameronjroe Latest istanbul (v0.4.2 at time of this writing) cannot instrument your tests when Mocha's `--compilers` option is used; you must use `babel-node`.  From what I can tell, istanbul v1.0.0 should not need `babel-node`.

Comment: @boneskull Okay, I'll use `babel-node` for now. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the `nyc` instructions. I was able to get that going when no magic combo of `babel-istanbul` and related modules could.

Comment: babel lets me specify the present in the cli, is their a way to parse it to babel-core/register when run with mocha? https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-using-presets i don't want a `.babelrc` file in my root folder

Comment: I like your 'Install a bunch of crap' approach. You seem to know how development using NPM works in reality.

Answer (score 26):

> PS: I now recommend to use single [**jest**](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) instead of mocha/instanbul/nyc/chai/etc.

---

## Solution A: Using [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) and [babel-plugin-istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul)

Setup <s>(don't forget `@next` for `nyc`)</s>:

```sh
npm install --save-dev nyc babel-plugin-istanbul babel-register
```

Add an env to `babel` config:

```
{
  "env": {
    "nyc": { "plugins": ["istanbul"] }
  }
}
```

`nyc` config:

```
{
  "reporter"   : ["text", "text-summary", "lcov", "html"],
  "include"    : ["src/**/*.js"],
  "require"    : ["babel-register"],
  "sourceMap"  : false,
  "instrument" : false,
  "all"        : true
}
```

PS: `include` field needs to be specified in `.nycrc` of in `package.json`, if specified in command line, coverage will not works

Running the tests:

```sh
# 1. Build
NODE_ENV=nyc babel src --out-dir lib

# 2. Coverage
nyc mocha
```

---

## Solution B: No extra packages : Only the basic ones

Work has been done recently on istanbul ([1.0.0-alpha.2](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha.2)) to support Babel generated code with sourcemaps (see [#212](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/212#issuecomment-160526692) and [this](https://github.com/istanbuljs/sample-babel-node) for an example).

There are 2 ways:

- A. Tests written against previously transpiled code
- B. Tests written against original code and transpiled all together in memory at runtime

### B1. Tests that exports (previously) transpiled code

This is done in 2 steps: Firstly, build your source with babel (e.g. from ./src to ./out) and write your tests against transpiled source (`export foo from "./out/foo";`).

Then you will be able to run the tests using istanbul [1.0.0-alpha.2](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha.2) :

```
istanbul cover _mocha -- ./test --compilers js:babel-register
```

Now if you want code coverage to follow the original code you've written (not the transpiled one), make sure to build with [babel source-maps options](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) set to [both](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) :

```
babel ./src --out-dir ./out --source-maps both
```

PS: If needed you can also do :

```
istanbul cover _mocha -- ./test --compilers js:babel-register \
   --require babel-polyfill \
   --require should \
   --require sinon
```

### B2. Tests that directly exports original code

In this case you write your tests against original source (`export foo from "./src/foo";`), and with no further step, you directly run istanbul [1.0.0-alpha.2](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha.2) using babel-node against cli.js :

```
babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover _mocha -- ./test
```

PS: If needed you can also do :

```
babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover _mocha -- ./test
   --require babel-polyfill \
   --require should \
   --require sinon
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had to use slightly different syntax: `istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- ./test --compilers js:babel-core/register`

Comment: Yep, upgrading to the alpha version does take care of problems with babel and Mocha. However, the resulting report cannot be combined with reports produced through `karma-coverage` which uses istanbul 0.4.x.

Comment: I've found switching to `nyc` extremely straightforward - just install, provide the source tree and extensions and it worked out of the box with pretty complex tech stack. Wonder if it could be that simple for `jest` as well? Maybe you know some documentation?

Answer (score 4):

As of now 17.4.2016 this coverage reporting stuff is still a bit messy and with my React-project that has .jsx files and a helper file the coverage reporting script looks like this:

```
istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- \
   --compilers js:babel-core/register \
   --require ./test/testhelper.js  \
   \"test/**/*@(.js|.jsx)\"
```

So it wouldn't be too easy the current version 0.4.3 of Istanbul doesn't work with Babel so you have to use the experimental alpha-version:

```
npm install istanbul@1.0.0-alpha.2 --save-dev
```

And then you need `.istanbul.yml` -file so that Istanbul recognizes the .jsx-files with these lines:

```
instrumentation:
  root: .
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
```

And now it should work. Also as a small bonus if you want to add coverage reporting with Travis and Coveralls you should:

1. enable the project in https://coveralls.io
2. add coveralls `npm i coveralls --save-dev`
3. add this to your `.travis.yml`:

   ```
   script:
     - npm --silent test
     - cat ./c
   coverage/lcov.info | coveralls
   ```

And now you can put that cool badge to your README. Neato!

Comment: Yep, upgrading to the alpha version does take care of problems with babel and Mocha. However, the resulting report cannot be combined with reports produced through `karma-coverage` which uses istanbul 0.4.x.