# Generate coverage with Mocha and Istanbul

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, code-coverage

I was testing my app with Jest, but how it's so hard to find documentation on internet I changed to Mocha

Now I'm trying to generate the coverage.

In my package.json I put the line to test:

```
scripts: {
     ...
     "test": "mocha './src/__tests__/**/*.test.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register"
}
```

What do I need to generate the coverage with Istanbul or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Mocha + Istanbul + Babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621079/running-mocha-istanbul-babel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code coverage with Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633246/code-coverage-with-mocha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in my `scripts` block (among others):

```
  "scripts": {
    "cover": "node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -R spec test"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use isparta for code coverage since it will give the coverage for the ES6 code rather than ES5 code. Here is a very good article which I followed to generate the code coverage: https://onsen.io/blog/mocha-chaijs-unit-test-coverage-es6/. Please do check it and let me know if you are able to generate the coverage.